# What is the meaning of ".*" when set permission in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I can use the rabbitmqctl to create a user:

```
rabbitmqctl add_user openstack password
```

Follow the tutorial, I can set the permission of the user:

```
rabbitmqctl set_permissions openstack ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

But what is the meaning of `".*"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [RabbitMQ documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html#set_permissions)

> set_permissions [-p vhost] {user} {conf} {write} {read}

`".*" ".*" ".*"` are three regular expressions and are going to be applied as conf, write, and read in order.In regular expression `.` match any characters, and `*` match any number of the following characters